# How can I use Windows Authentication with Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient

Tags: c#, .net, windows-authentication, autorest

I have a `Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient` generated with `autorest`. And I want to access a REST API secured with Windows Authentication and Basic Authentication.

The goal is to use Windows Authentication. I tried it as follows:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
};
this.InitializeHttpClient(handler);
```

This does not work, I get:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. 
---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. 
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The target principal name is incorrect
```

When I use Basic Authentication it works.

```
this.Credentials = new BasicAuthenticationCredentials
{
    UserName = Configuration.User,
    Password = Configuration.Password
};
```

This setup of the `ServiceClient` is done in the constructor of

```
MyClient : Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient
```

What do I need to add to the client to get Windows Authentication working?

**Edited:**

It looks like the problem is on server side. Settings in IIS.

The client would work as expected.

Comment: Is the process running under your Windows principal or another account?

Comment: I tried both, but as mentioned in the question, the client woks correct.

Answer (score 3):

This basically reiterates what's already covered in the OP and by @Anders, in my preferred syntax...

```
 var windowsAuthHandler = new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
 var webApiUri = new System.Uri("https://localhost:8080");
 var apiClient = new MyAutoRestClient(webApiUri ,windowsAuthHandler);
```

If you're skimming, the OP seems to indicate this doesn't work, when, indeed it does. But, as the OP later states, be sure to start with IIS to make sure it's configured right

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar solution for passing on Windows credentials, and it works nicely.
The only difference is that I use the constructor overload of `ServiceClient` that takes a `HttpClientHandler` instance, rather than calling `InitializeHttpClient()` and it looks something like this:

```
public class MyClient : ServiceClient<MyClient>
{
    public MyClient() : base(new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true }) {}
}
```

However, the part of your 401-message that says "The target principal name is incorrect" looks suspicious. Your problem may arise from some issues in your AD-configuration rather than in the `ServiceClient`-configuration.

Answer (score 0):

@bkwdesign has right

```
var credentials = new Microsoft.Rest.BasicAuthenticationCredentials();
var handler = new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
var uri = new Uri("http://your-rest-api:8008");
var svc = new WebApplication1Client(uri, credentials, handler);

//WebApplication1Client : ServiceClient<WebApplication1Client>, IWebApplication1Client
```

This is the way how to pass credentials from MVC to WebAPI Windows Authentication or impersonate credentials

Maybe other options:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials };
var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials };
```